# How to change the icon of the WPF datepicker?

Tags: wpf, datepicker

I'm doing a wpf application where i have two datepicker inside my application. I want to know is that any quick way(like the way i set my datepicker background) for me to change the calendar icon of the wpf default datepicker?

my datepicker code snippet:

```
  <DatePicker Name="datefromDP" Width="100" Height="24"Foreground="White" BorderThickness="0"  >
        <DatePicker.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type DatePickerTextBox}">
                <Setter Property="Text" Value="Select date" />
                <Setter Property="IsReadOnly" Value="True"/>
                <Setter Property="Background">
                  <Setter.Value>
                    <ImageBrush ImageSource="/BeaconProject;component/B_images/button/loginheader_bg.jpg"/>
                  </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </DatePicker.Resources>
  </DatePicker>
```

my datepicker:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think you should Use your own style. see [DatePicker Style](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/framework/wpf/controls/datepicker-syles-and-templates).

The Icon you are referring to is this part of the style:

```
<Path HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="4,3,4,3" ...
<Ellipse HorizontalAlignment="Center" ...
<Border Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="4" ...
```

Comment: cannot find xmlns:vsm="clr-namespace:System.Windows;assembly=System.Windows" and 
xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls"....what references i need to add?

Comment: @0070 it is written there; Under `Default Style and Template`: <!-- XML Namespace mappings. -->
xmlns:vsm="clr-namespace:System.Windows;assembly=System.Windows"
xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls"