# How to hide datepicker icon in wpf C#?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datepicker

I want to hide the default  `DatePicker` icon:

[image]

I need something like:

```
 <DatePicker IconVisibality="False"/>
```

I tried:

```
Template="{x:Null}"
```

but it hides all.

I also tried:

```
Foreground="{x:Null}"
```

**Does anyone know?**

Comment: Two questions: why and what did you try to do so?

Comment: Did you try anything? Because such questions have high probability of being asked already [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14035379/1997232) (pity, the deleted answer there would be useful to you). WPF is pretty flexible as you can [change style](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/styling-and-templating) of almost anything.

Comment: @Rafalon  that's because I'm opening the dialog via other event

Comment: @Sinatr there is no accepted answer on the first link, the second link is too general, I'm looking for spesific answer to my question

Comment: Did you search online? [How to change `DatePicker` icon](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f7b855be-8621-42b8-b109-e1c8b63cdfa4/how-to-change-datapicker-icon?forum=wpf) / [How to remove default Image of `DatePicker`](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/e98c290c-19ed-486a-aeba-22be20aa1b1f/how-to-remove-default-image-of-datepicker?forum=wpf) were the two first links of a quick google search

Comment: @Rafalon Have you read the links? the first deals with **changing** the icon, the second doen't provide the answer

Comment: Well I've read this "*You can use following code in case you want to remove button completely*" in the second link which lead me to think the "following code" is an answer. Also "*To **remove/change** the image [...] you can change the xaml for "**DropDownButtonTemplate**"*" - which seems to be what the first link was also referring to

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A lighter way would be to create a custom control.

```
public class CustomDatePicker:DatePicker
{
    public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();

        if (Template.FindName("PART_Button", this) is Button button)
        {
            button.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;
        }
    }
}
```

And then consume it in Xaml

```html
<local:CustomDatePicker   />
```

Comment: Great! Thank you! I wrote `Visibility.Collaped` instead of `Visibility.Hidden` **:-)**

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a custom template. You could right-click on a `DatePicker` element in design mode in Visual Studio or in Blend and choose Edit Template->Edit a Copy to copy the default template into your XAML markup, and then remove the `Button` element named "PART_Button" from it:

```
<DatePicker>
    <DatePicker.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DatePicker}">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF333333"/>
            <Setter Property="IsTodayHighlighted" Value="True"/>
            <Setter Property="SelectedDateFormat" Value="Short"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="2"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint=".5,0" StartPoint=".5,1">
                        <GradientStop Color="#FFA3AEB9" Offset="0"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="#FF8399A9" Offset="0.375"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="#FF718597" Offset="0.375"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="#FF617584" Offset="1"/>
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DatePicker}">
                        <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="PART_DisabledVisual"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <Grid x:Name="PART_Root" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}">
                                <Grid.Resources>
                                    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="DisabledBrush" Color="#A5FFFFFF"/>
                                    <ControlTemplate x:Key="DropDownButtonTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                                        <Grid>
                                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                                    <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                                        <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0"/>
                                                        <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.1" To="MouseOver"/>
                                                        <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.1" To="Pressed"/>
                                                    </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                                    <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                                                        <Storyboard>
                                                            <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="#FF448DCA" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="Background"/>
                                                            <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0" Duration="00:00:00.001" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[3].(GradientStop.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradient">
                                                                <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#7FFFFFFF"/>
                                                            </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                            <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0" Duration="00:00:00.001" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[2].(GradientStop.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradient">
                                                                <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#CCFFFFFF"/>
                                                            </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                            <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0" Duration="00:00:00.001" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradient">
                                                                <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#F2FFFFFF"/>
                                                            </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                        </Storyboard>
                                                    </VisualState>
                                                    <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                                        <Storyboard>
                                                            <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0" Duration="00:00:00.001" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="Background">
                                                                <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#FF448DCA"/>
                                                            </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0" Duration="00:00:00.001" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="Highlight">
                                                                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
                                                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                            <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0" Duration="00:00:00.001" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradient">
                                                                <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#EAFFFFFF"/>
                                                            </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                            <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0" Duration="00:00:00.001" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[2].(GradientStop.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradient">
                                                                <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#C6FFFFFF"/>
                                                            </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                            <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0" Duration="00:00:00.001" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[3].(GradientStop.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradient">
                                                                <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#6BFFFFFF"/>
                                                            </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                            <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0" Duration="00:00:00.001" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[0].(GradientStop.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradient">
                                                                <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#F4FFFFFF"/>
                                                            </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                        </Storyboard>
                                                    </VisualState>
                                                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled"/>
                                                </VisualStateGroup>
                                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                            <Grid Background="#11FFFFFF" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="18" Margin="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="19">
                                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="20*"/>
                                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="20*"/>
                                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="20*"/>
                                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="20*"/>
                                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                    <RowDefinition Height="23*"/>
                                                    <RowDefinition Height="19*"/>
                                                    <RowDefinition Height="19*"/>
                                                    <RowDefinition Height="19*"/>
                                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                <Border x:Name="Highlight" BorderBrush="#FF45D6FA" BorderThickness="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" CornerRadius="0,0,1,1" Margin="-1" Opacity="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="4"/>
                                                <Border x:Name="Background" BorderBrush="#FFFFFFFF" BorderThickness="1" Background="#FF1F3B53" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" CornerRadius=".5" Margin="0,-1,0,0" Opacity="1" Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="3"/>
                                                <Border x:Name="BackgroundGradient" BorderBrush="#BF000000" BorderThickness="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" CornerRadius=".5" Margin="0,-1,0,0" Opacity="1" Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="3">
                                                    <Border.Background>
                                                        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint=".7,1" StartPoint=".7,0">
                                                            <GradientStop Color="#FFFFFFFF" Offset="0"/>
                                                            <GradientStop Color="#F9FFFFFF" Offset="0.375"/>
                                                            <GradientStop Color="#E5FFFFFF" Offset="0.625"/>
                                                            <GradientStop Color="#C6FFFFFF" Offset="1"/>
                                                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                                                    </Border.Background>
                                                </Border>
                                                <Rectangle Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Grid.RowSpan="1" StrokeThickness="1">
                                                    <Rectangle.Fill>
                                                        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.3,-1.1" StartPoint="0.46,1.6">
                                                            <GradientStop Color="#FF4084BD"/>
                                                            <GradientStop Color="#FFAFCFEA" Offset="1"/>
                                                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                                                    </Rectangle.Fill>
                                                    <Rectangle.Stroke>
                                                        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.48,-1" StartPoint="0.48,1.25">
                                                            <GradientStop Color="#FF494949"/>
                                                            <GradientStop Color="#FF9F9F9F" Offset="1"/>
                                                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                                                    </Rectangle.Stroke>
                                                </Rectangle>
                                                <Path Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Grid.Column="0" Data="M11.426758,8.4305077 L11.749023,8.4305077 L11.749023,16.331387 L10.674805,16.331387 L10.674805,10.299648 L9.0742188,11.298672 L9.0742188,10.294277 C9.4788408,10.090176 9.9094238,9.8090878 10.365967,9.4510155 C10.82251,9.0929432 11.176106,8.7527733 11.426758,8.4305077 z M14.65086,8.4305077 L18.566387,8.4305077 L18.566387,9.3435936 L15.671368,9.3435936 L15.671368,11.255703 C15.936341,11.058764 16.27293,10.960293 16.681133,10.960293 C17.411602,10.960293 17.969301,11.178717 18.354229,11.615566 C18.739157,12.052416 18.931622,12.673672 18.931622,13.479336 C18.931622,15.452317 18.052553,16.438808 16.294415,16.438808 C15.560365,16.438808 14.951641,16.234707 14.468243,15.826504 L14.881817,14.929531 C15.368796,15.326992 15.837872,15.525723 16.289043,15.525723 C17.298809,15.525723 17.803692,14.895514 17.803692,13.635098 C17.803692,12.460618 17.305971,11.873379 16.310528,11.873379 C15.83071,11.873379 15.399232,12.079271 15.016094,12.491055 L14.65086,12.238613 z" Fill="#FF2F2F2F" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="4,3,4,3" Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="3" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                                <Ellipse Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Fill="#FFFFFFFF" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="3" StrokeThickness="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="3"/>
                                                <Border x:Name="DisabledVisual" BorderBrush="#B2FFFFFF" BorderThickness="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" CornerRadius="0,0,.5,.5" Opacity="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="4"/>
                                            </Grid>
                                        </Grid>
                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                </Grid.Resources>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <!--<Button x:Name="PART_Button" Grid.Column="1" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" Focusable="False" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="3,0,3,0" Grid.Row="0" Template="{StaticResource DropDownButtonTemplate}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="20"/>-->
                                <DatePickerTextBox x:Name="PART_TextBox" Grid.Column="0" Focusable="{TemplateBinding Focusable}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="0" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"/>
                                <Grid x:Name="PART_DisabledVisual" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Column="0" IsHitTestVisible="False" Opacity="0" Grid.Row="0">
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <Rectangle Grid.Column="0" Fill="#A5FFFFFF" RadiusY="1" Grid.Row="0" RadiusX="1"/>
                                    <Rectangle Grid.Column="1" Fill="#A5FFFFFF" Height="18" Margin="3,0,3,0" RadiusY="1" Grid.Row="0" RadiusX="1" Width="19"/>
                                    <Popup x:Name="PART_Popup" AllowsTransparency="True" Placement="Bottom" PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=PART_TextBox}" StaysOpen="False"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Source={x:Static SystemParameters.HighContrast}}" Value="false">
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" TargetName="PART_TextBox" Value="{Binding Foreground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </DatePicker.Style>
</DatePicker>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just override your template with another style (like this) and reference it with StaticResource to your DatePicker.

```
<Style x:Key="WithoutButtonPickerStyle" TargetType="{x:Type DatePicker}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
          <Setter.Value>
              <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DatePicker}">
                     <Grid x:Name="PART_Root" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                         <DatePickerTextBox x:Name="PART_TextBox">...</DatePickerTextBox>
                         <Button x:Name="PART_Button" Visibility="Hidden"/>
                     </Grid>
               </ControlTemplate>
           </Setter.Value>
     </Setter>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="DatePickerStyle" TargetType="{x:Type DatePicker}">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF333333"/>
        <Setter Property="IsTodayHighlighted" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="SelectedDateFormat" Value="Short"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="2"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush">
            <Setter.Value>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint=".5,0" StartPoint=".5,1">
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFA3AEB9" Offset="0"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF8399A9" Offset="0.375"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF718597" Offset="0.375"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF617584" Offset="1"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DatePicker}">
                    <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="PART_DisabledVisual"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <Grid x:Name="PART_Root" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}">
                            <Grid.Resources>
                                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="DisabledBrush" Color="#A5FFFFFF"/>
                                <ControlTemplate x:Key="DropDownButtonTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                                    <Grid>
                                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                                <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                                    <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0"/>
                                                    <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.1" To="MouseOver"/>
                                                    <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.1" To="Pressed"/>
                                                </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                                <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                                                    <Storyboard>
                                                        <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="#FF448DCA" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="Background"/>
                                                        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0" Duration="00:00:00.001" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[3].(GradientStop.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradient">
                                                            <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#7FFFFFFF"/>
                                                        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0" Duration="00:00:00.001" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[2].(GradientStop.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradient">
                                                            <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#CCFFFFFF"/>
                                                        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0" Duration="00:00:00.001" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradient">
                                                            <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#F2FFFFFF"/>
                                                        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                    </Storyboard>
                                                </VisualState>
                                                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                                    <Storyboard>
                                                        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0" Duration="00:00:00.001" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="Background">
                                                            <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#FF448DCA"/>
                                                        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0" Duration="00:00:00.001" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="Highlight">
                                                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
                                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0" Duration="00:00:00.001" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradient">
                                                            <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#EAFFFFFF"/>
                                                        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0" Duration="00:00:00.001" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[2].(GradientStop.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradient">
                                                            <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#C6FFFFFF"/>
                                                        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0" Duration="00:00:00.001" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[3].(GradientStop.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradient">
                                                            <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#6BFFFFFF"/>
                                                        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0" Duration="00:00:00.001" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[0].(GradientStop.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradient">
                                                            <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#F4FFFFFF"/>
                                                        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                    </Storyboard>
                                                </VisualState>
                                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled"/>
                                            </VisualStateGroup>
                                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                        <Grid Background="#11FFFFFF" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="18" Margin="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="19">
                                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="20*"/>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="20*"/>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="20*"/>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="20*"/>
                                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                <RowDefinition Height="23*"/>
                                                <RowDefinition Height="19*"/>
                                                <RowDefinition Height="19*"/>
                                                <RowDefinition Height="19*"/>
                                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                            <Border x:Name="Highlight" BorderBrush="#FF45D6FA" BorderThickness="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" CornerRadius="0,0,1,1" Margin="-1" Opacity="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="4"/>
                                            <Border x:Name="Background" BorderBrush="#FFFFFFFF" BorderThickness="1" Background="#FF1F3B53" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" CornerRadius=".5" Margin="0,-1,0,0" Opacity="1" Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="3"/>
                                            <Border x:Name="BackgroundGradient" BorderBrush="#BF000000" BorderThickness="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" CornerRadius=".5" Margin="0,-1,0,0" Opacity="1" Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="3">
                                                <Border.Background>
                                                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint=".7,1" StartPoint=".7,0">
                                                        <GradientStop Color="#FFFFFFFF" Offset="0"/>
                                                        <GradientStop Color="#F9FFFFFF" Offset="0.375"/>
                                                        <GradientStop Color="#E5FFFFFF" Offset="0.625"/>
                                                        <GradientStop Color="#C6FFFFFF" Offset="1"/>
                                                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                                                </Border.Background>
                                            </Border>
                                            <Rectangle Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Grid.RowSpan="1" StrokeThickness="1">
                                                <Rectangle.Fill>
                                                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.3,-1.1" StartPoint="0.46,1.6">
                                                        <GradientStop Color="#FF4084BD"/>
                                                        <GradientStop Color="#FFAFCFEA" Offset="1"/>
                                                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                                                </Rectangle.Fill>
                                                <Rectangle.Stroke>
                                                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.48,-1" StartPoint="0.48,1.25">
                                                        <GradientStop Color="#FF494949"/>
                                                        <GradientStop Color="#FF9F9F9F" Offset="1"/>
                                                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                                                </Rectangle.Stroke>
                                            </Rectangle>
                                            <Path Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Grid.Column="0" Data="M11.426758,8.4305077 L11.749023,8.4305077 L11.749023,16.331387 L10.674805,16.331387 L10.674805,10.299648 L9.0742188,11.298672 L9.0742188,10.294277 C9.4788408,10.090176 9.9094238,9.8090878 10.365967,9.4510155 C10.82251,9.0929432 11.176106,8.7527733 11.426758,8.4305077 z M14.65086,8.4305077 L18.566387,8.4305077 L18.566387,9.3435936 L15.671368,9.3435936 L15.671368,11.255703 C15.936341,11.058764 16.27293,10.960293 16.681133,10.960293 C17.411602,10.960293 17.969301,11.178717 18.354229,11.615566 C18.739157,12.052416 18.931622,12.673672 18.931622,13.479336 C18.931622,15.452317 18.052553,16.438808 16.294415,16.438808 C15.560365,16.438808 14.951641,16.234707 14.468243,15.826504 L14.881817,14.929531 C15.368796,15.326992 15.837872,15.525723 16.289043,15.525723 C17.298809,15.525723 17.803692,14.895514 17.803692,13.635098 C17.803692,12.460618 17.305971,11.873379 16.310528,11.873379 C15.83071,11.873379 15.399232,12.079271 15.016094,12.491055 L14.65086,12.238613 z" Fill="#FF2F2F2F" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="4,3,4,3" Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="3" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                            <Ellipse Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Fill="#FFFFFFFF" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="3" StrokeThickness="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="3"/>
                                            <Border x:Name="DisabledVisual" BorderBrush="#B2FFFFFF" BorderThickness="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" CornerRadius="0,0,.5,.5" Opacity="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="4"/>
                                        </Grid>
                                    </Grid>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Grid.Resources>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <!--This is Button Templete-->
                            <Button x:Name="PART_Button" Grid.Column="1" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" Focusable="False" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="3,0,3,0" Grid.Row="0"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="20"/>
                            <!--...-->
                            <DatePickerTextBox x:Name="PART_TextBox" Grid.Column="0" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" Focusable="{TemplateBinding Focusable}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="0" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"/>
                            <Grid x:Name="PART_DisabledVisual" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Column="0" IsHitTestVisible="False" Opacity="0" Grid.Row="0">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Rectangle Grid.Column="0" Fill="#A5FFFFFF" RadiusY="1" Grid.Row="0" RadiusX="1"/>
                                <Rectangle Grid.Column="1" Fill="#A5FFFFFF" Height="18" Margin="3,0,3,0" RadiusY="1" Grid.Row="0" RadiusX="1" Width="19"/>
                                <Popup x:Name="PART_Popup" AllowsTransparency="True" Placement="Bottom" PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=PART_TextBox}" StaysOpen="False"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <DatePicker Width="150" Height="26" Style="{StaticResource DatePickerStyle}"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Consider to add a few words explaining keypoints and details of your answer: how it works and why. The xaml comment is barely visible inside such a long code snippet.